# angular httpinterceptor always call success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I've got this $http interceptor:

```
app.factory('offlineInterceptor', ["$q", function ($q) {
    return {  
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 0 && mycondition) {
                ??????????
            } else {
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

In case of error I need that the interceptor traps the error and returns a fixed value like 0.

I tried to do `$q.resolve(0);` but when I do

```
    $http.success(function(data){

    })
```

`data` is fine in case of success, but is undefined in case of error.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: `success` is deprecated...should be using `then()` and catch()..see docs